I am flying from Manchester on Lufthansa to Frankfurt then on to Vancouver with Air Canada Same ticket. Do I need to clear Immigration?
From what read on hear I may have too. Layover is 1 hour 10 min

What makes you think you would need to?

You're arriving from a non-Schengen country and going to a non-Schengen country
Both flights are on the same ticket, so your luggage will be checked through
Frankfurt has sterile airside transit

So you won't need to enter or exit the Schengen Area.
You may have to go through security, but you won't need to clear immigration in Frankfurt.

Thanks just some comments I have read on other forums. Appreciate you clearing this up!

As the OP doesn’t say why they are asking, or give their citizenship, it might be worth mentioning that in some instances an airside transit visa might be required.

@Traveller shouldn't be necessary in this case if they have the paperwork for Canada, I guess. I'm not sure there are any cases when one could enter Canada and need an ATV inside Schengen, or are there?
